# Can't get div to stay inline or expand correctly

Tags: html, css, inline

I'm starting from scratch with a new and more efficient menu layout.
 However, I thought I had it made until I hit another problem. I've attached a picture of what **shouldn't** be happening: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7wmna7yb7qzm5s/Capture.PNG?dl=0).

What I need is for everything in this grey menu bar to stay aligned no matter the size of the window

And everything in the red to stay in line under the same circumstances.

Here is my code:

```html
<style>
  * {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .menuHead {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: #666;
    /*inline block padding fix*/
    font-size: 0;
  }
  
  .menuHeadElement {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .siteLogo {
    border: 2px solid white;
    margin-left: 3%;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .menuBar {
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 3%;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .menuSelection {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 3%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  </stlye><body><div class="menuHead"><div class="siteLogo menuHeadElement"><a href="#"><img src="media/images/site/npLog.png" height="160px"></img></a></div><div class="menuBar menuHeadElement"><div class="menuSelection">Home </div><div class="menuSelection">About </div><div class="menuSelection">Contact </div><div class="menuSelection">Gallo </div></div></div><div class="bgVid"><video id="mnScrnVid" src="media/video/WebVid.mp4" autoplay muted/></div></body>
```

It seems the red div `menuBar` only expands to a certain amount and then starts to wrap everything floating in it. Stumped.

Comment: Do you want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/26on9fbx/)

Answer (score 0):

you are using px to assign the width.

try using `width: 10%;` or `width:30%;`
this will make it so when you resize the window, it will always take that % of the screen width. not a set PX

Comment: that is just the set size of the button....and it breaks the menuBar div even more. menuBar does keep expanding based on the floating content. and then, when minimes enough, menuBar falls under the whole thing. and the menuSelections still wrap down....

Comment: the only way i know to make that happen is by using the 'position: fixed;' css. this makes it so when you minimize the window, it simply disappears behind the window

Comment: So you want the logo & menu to stay on the same line, and the menu-items within the menu to stay on the same line also, right? -- edit: just saw that this question is from 4 years ago. It showed up on the new questions list because of an edit. nvm.